# Substitution for integrals two different cases.

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

In my book they make the point that: "The method of substitution cannot be force to work".

They then go on to say that: "there is no substitution that will do much good with the integral $\int x(2+x^7)^{\frac{1}{5}}dx $ "

However, the integral  $\int x^6(2+x^7)^{\frac{1}{5}}dx $ does apparently yield a substitution for $2+x^7$. Where $u=2+x^7$

Why is this? What distinguishes the two, obviously the order of the exponent $x$ and $x^6$ does something. But I am unsure about what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $$z=2+x^7$$
$$dz=7x^6dx\\\text{or}$$
$$x^6dx=dz/7$$
This means, $$\int x^6(2+x^7)^{1/5}dx=\int\frac{1}{7} z^{1/5}dz\\\text{which can easily be calculated to be equal to }\frac{5z^{6/5}}{42}.$$
Note that nothing of this sort could happen in the case $x^1$, since it won't come out to be of the form of the differentiation of $2+x^7$.

Comment: I see. Thank you!